# When updating a row based update in the datatable, the table is refreshed when it closes the modal

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, datatable, datatables, refresh

When I update and save the line from the datatable and close the modal, it does not update.
When I type the name datatable in the complete section, it gives an error and the old list keeps coming up. How can I update the list?

```
   $.ajax({
            ....
            ....
     success: function (data) {
                   
             },
             complete: function () {
                 setTimeout(function () {
                     $('#TechDocUpdateModal').modal('hide');
                 }, 100)
             },
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I type the name datatable in the complete section, it gives an error and the old list keeps coming up. How can I update the list?

Ajax is used without refreshing the page.If you want to refresh the page,Why not using normal form submit?

If you must use ajax to refresh the page,you could use `window.location.href` to redirect and refresh the page:

```
success: function () {
        $('#TechDocUpdateModal').modal('hide');
        window.location.href = "YourUrl";
}
```

Here is a working demo:

Model:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog>
<h1>Index</h1>
<button type="button" id="btn1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Create</button>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.BlogId">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.BlogId">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.BlogId">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="Close()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="details">
                <form>
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                        <input name="Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ElementAt(0).Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="button" id="Add" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="Close()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
@section Scripts
{
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script>
        $('#Add').click(() => {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Blogs/Create",
                method: "POST",
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
                    window.location.href = "/Blogs/Index";
                }
            })

        })
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class BlogsController : Controller
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;

    public BlogsController(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Blogs
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Blogs.ToListAsync());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Create([Bind("BlogId,Name")] Blog blog)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(blog);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        //do your stuff...
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the advice. When I use window.location.href it refreshes the page. There is a button to filter on my page and when I click that button the datatable is filled.
When I use window.location, the data coming with datatable is also lost. but I need the table from the datatable with the updated information after the modal closes. My table doesn't load when I try this.

Comment: So could you please share more details?You need share code which could reproduce your issue,otherwise we will never know how to resolve the issue.